# ec2 high storage instances, can it be used for couchdb or other db

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchdb

As far as I know instance storage on ec2 is ephemeral ie it is lost when the instance is restarted.  Is this different for high storage instances?  if not it would seem that you would lose any database data stored on the instance upon restart.

Answer (score 0):

Ebs backed volumes should be used for storage. Either you can take standard storage or iops. This will avoid any data losses due to instance going down.

When you attach the ebs volume to instance, make sure a entry is made to fstab file. So when you reboot the instance the volume is still attached. When you stop an instance, the data is present but the hardware is released while reboot is just like your system restarts.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.  Does this not render these high storage instances, that they say are for databases, totally useless?

Comment: When you look at the ec2 instances, they are categorized based on memory usage, computation and grouped accordingly. Amazon always suggests to go for ebs for storing data, instance memory can be utilized for the processes running.

Answer (score 0):

All ephemeral storage is lost if the instance is stopped. You can still use a database with the high IO storage instances, but you will need to replicate the data between several instances to attain persistence.